# How to set up a DNS server on ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, mysql, dns

This DNS server will use to access a web server/ mysql server.
Scenario:
DNS Server of 192.168.0.0/24 network - 192.168.0.2
domain name(dn): my.site.com redirect to 192.168.2.1 (webserver/mysqlserver)
or we may try
(dn)my2.site.com **

What will be the steps to configure this scenario?
Having a DNS server, web server / sql server.

Comment: Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/330148/bind9-complete-dns-server-configuration-with-hostname-step-by-step) tutorial out....